# calculation on each array member

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, lodash

Given an array of arrays representing points, I want to find the minimum distance between points and return that distance and that starting point.  I am using lodash and would like to be as functional as possible.

I have an array of arrays:

```
var all = [[1,2], [3,4], [4,5]];
```

I also have an object which has the current minimum distance and current array:

```
var cur_min = {'current_min': 10, 'point': [9,10]};
```

I want to find the minimum distance between all of the points in my array and if that distance is less than the current_min in my cur_min variable it will be updated. I have come up with the following:

```
function find_new_min(current, arr) {
    return _.transform(arr, function(result, a) {
                _.forEach(arr, function(b) {
                    if (!_.isEqual(a,b)) {
                        var d = get_distance(a,b);
                        if (d<result.current_min) {
                            result.current_min = d;
                            result.point = a;
                        }
                    }
                });
            }, _.clone(current));
}
```

I am expecting 6 different pairs of arrays since getting the distance between a point and itself is 0.

I cannot imagine looping over the same array twice is an efficient way to solve this problem. I've tried to rewrite this function using various lodash functions like _.forEach and _.reduce but I cannot find a way to not loop twice over the same array. Is there a faster way to solve this problem?

an example output for the above code is:

```
{ current_min: 1.222450611061632, loc: [ 1, 2 ] }
```

Comment: Can you post an example of output?

Comment: Not sure how you define "efficiency" but talking speed its way faster to manually iterate the array than using iterator functions and all that. Especially when you're expecting 6 pairs.

Comment: I want it to be able to take any length array. 6 is just an example here. Looping over the same array twice can't be efficient.

Comment: Trust me when i say you calling functions, switching scopes, adding to the stack, on every element of an array multiple times is not efficient. There's more to efficiency then just the count of reading the same data. also i dont know why one would need to iterate that array twice to find the smallest min distance but this may be due to the fact i dont quite get what you're asking.

Comment: Or wait, dont trust me and do a benchmark on jsperf.com and see yourself.

Comment: I trust you. Do you have an example how I can improve this? That was my question - I don't know how to improve the current solution.

Comment: So you want to find the two points that are closest to each other, and the actual distance between them? current_min beeing the distance and loc beeing the indices inside the points array?

Comment: yes, that's correct. Where am I switching scopes, etc?

Comment: You're switching scopes with every function you enter, so you anonymous iterator functions as well as your function calls.
I'm preparing some code for you, please stand by ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60208/discussion-between-ptrkcon-and-lj-1102).

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is one of the oldest: how to most efficiently sort an array of values based on some functional key. However, you also want to record the shortest distance and for that you need to compare to each and every other value. Because of this, you can't efficiently sort, you need to run over the entire array `array.length` times.

Considering you're expecting only six pairs of points, this seems like a severe case of [premature optimization](https://shreevatsa.wordpress.com/2008/05/16/premature-optimization-is-the-root-of-all-evil/).

Readability-wise, unfortunately lodash doesn't offer functionality to produce a Cartesian product which you could then `_.sortBy`, nor does it offer a sort function that allows you to compare manually left and right and modify the values. I think your current implementation currently is as good as it gets with lodash.